# style css in javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create something like a little editor in javascript, but I don't understand why the .style doesn't work..

Thanks in advance for the help!

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <textarea cols="30" rows="1" id="title1">write here the header</textarea><br /><br />
        <textarea cols="30" rows="1" id="desc1">write here the paragraph</textarea>
        <input type="button" value="show" onclick="doit()">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doit() {
        var title = document.getElementById("title1").value;
        var desc = document.getElementById("desc1").value;
        document.write("<h1>"+title+"</h1>").style.color="blue";
        document.write(desc);
    }
</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `document.write` is not a good idea use `append` instead

Comment: document.write does not return a DOM element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `document.write`, see the warning from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29):

> **Warning!** This method has very idiosyncratic behavior. In some cases, this method can affect the state of the HTML parser while the
>   parser is running, resulting in a DOM that does not correspond to the
>   source of the document (e.g. if the string written is the string
>   "`<plaintext>`" or "`<!--`"). In other cases, the call can clear the
>   current page first, as if `document.open()` had been called. In yet more
>   cases, the method is simply ignored, or throws an exception. To make
>   matters worse, the exact behavior of this method can in some cases be
>   dependent on network latency, which can lead to failures that are very
>   hard to debug. **For all these reasons, use of this method is strongly
>   discouraged.**

Use DOM methods instead:

```
function doit() {
    var title = document.getElementById("title1").value,
        desc = document.getElementById("desc1").value,
        h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
    h1.style.color="blue";
    document.body.appendChild(h1);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(desc));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
document.write("<h1 style='color:blue'>"+title+"</h1>");
```

Comment: Please elaborate on why you think this answer might solve the problem, instead of just dropping some code.

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3SWxs/)

```
<div id="container">
<textarea cols="30" rows="1" id="title1">write here the header</textarea><br /><br />
<textarea cols="30" rows="1" id="desc1">write here the paragraph</textarea>
<input type="button" value="show" onclick="doit();" />
<h1 id="header" style="color:blue;"></h1>
<p id="par"></p>
</div>

function doit() {
var title = document.getElementById("title1").value;
var desc = document.getElementById("desc1").value;
document.getElementById('header').innerHTML=title;
document.getElementById('par').innerHTML=desc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doit() {
    var title = document.getElementById("title1").value;
    var desc = document.getElementById("desc1").value;

    var newheader = document.createElement("h1");
    newheader.innerHTML = "title";
    newheader.style.color = "blue";
    document.body.appendChild(newheader);

    var newspan = document.createElement("span");
    newspan.innerHTML = desc;
    document.body.appendChild(newspan);

  }
</script>
```